# SD card suddenly damaged

Tags: external-sd

I'm using Xperia C. My SD card works perfectly fine but after I power down my phone and turn it back on, suddenly it says that my SD is damaged and I have to format it. I can't even mount it on my phone cuz when I do, it just unmount it again. This is not the first time it happen. Last time, it was with my first SD card and now, my second. What should I do?

Comment: Are both cards (old and new) from the same brand, and maybe even the same size? There are incompatibilities reported here and there, so you might want to try a different brand. You could check with some Xperia specialized forums to see what combinations others used successfully, and if maybe somebody else experienced the same trouble with your combination.

Comment: Both were 8GB Sandisk sd card. So now, i changed to Toshiba 8GB. It works fine now but let see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: So my guess was right at this point (so far). Don't forget to report back when you think you can tell the difference; might prove helpful to other Xperia C users :)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem less than an hour ago on my Acer Iconia a500. I've had it happen with multiple SD cards on different devices. This is how I overcome this problem everytime. The only way that this wont work is if the card is fried

To the problem of your "damaged SD card", what's most likely going is corruption of the file system. Something on the phone made an invalid entry.

1. Plug your SD card in the reader
2. Run Mini Tool Partition Wizard (MTPW)
3. Select Partition Wizard, other is Data Recovery
4. Pick the SD card in the list
5. Right click for drop down menu
6. Scroll down and click on *Check File System*
7. Let it finish, then exit MTPW
8. Unplug and re-plug SD card into reader
9. When "Do you want to scan and fix" pops up, check both
10. When finished, unplug from reader
11. Mount in your phone and enjoy.

I know it's a late answer,  but knowledge is power.