# "Corrupt" SD card after power off?

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery, adoptable-storage, data-corruption

I have a BQ-7082G ARMOR Android 7 device, with a SD card formatted as internal storage. One day it run out of battery, shut down, and afterwards it reported the SD card is corrupt and refuses to mount it. My only options offered by the device is to reformat it (external/internal storage), something I just won't do because there is some important data on it.

Complicating matters I can't easily at least make a backup of the card because I lack a suitable reader to connect to my PC.

Side note is I just don't understand how did it get damaged at all? There was no activity for like half a day and the only purpose the device fulfilled back then was to play music. Unfortunately, I got the stupid idea to take some photos with it the day before this happened and I'd like to get them all. Other than that there was no anything else I would lose my sleep over, although getting back everything would be nice.

How can I figure out what happened to the card so that hopefully I could fix just that somehow and have the device recognize the SD card properly?

Comment: Data on the SD-card formatted as internal is encrypted. Usually if Android has problems mounting the SD-card this is caused by problems with the encryption key. Unfortunately the encryption key is not accessible to users (unless the phone is rooted) which makes it next to impossible to recover from such situations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrypt the corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135803/how-to-decrypt-the-corrupt-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage)

Comment: @RohitGupta: no, because the primary focus of my question is to figure out the initial problem that rendered the SD card unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hell yeah, I think I managed to solve my troubles. I managed to find a suitable card reader initially to make a backup image of the SD card, but then decided to take a look at it using all the tools I had at my disposal, namely the Windows Disk Management console and MiniTool Partition Wizard. The first simply reported the drive as `RAW` and so was of little use other than to tell me that it has a single partition spanning the entire card as far as I can tell.

This was peculiar, as from what I'd gathered, SD cards formatted as internal storage should have two partitions. At this point I felt somewhat defeated,  that the SD card had entirely given out. But I was still after my data so continued digging. I was still hopeful it was just some kind of FS failure that scanning the drive for errors would correct once I found a way for Windows to recognize the drive as a valid volume.

The [SD card suddenly damaged](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/71751/sd-card-suddenly-damaged) question reminded me that I too have MTPW installed. I poked around and realized it does see the card properly as a FAT32 partition and can even explore its contents. I scanned the drive for errors. It did find some, so first I took an image backup of the drive as is, then run the FS check again allowing to correct errors this time. Immediately Windows has started to recognize the drive and it appears all contents is intact. Then I turned off my Android device, inserted the SD card and powered it on. This time it didn't present me with the "there is a problem with the SD card, pick your poison" notification, and even apps installed on it appear to be working.

IDK how come I didn't just lose all the data I desperately wanted to save given from all the research I'd done the feat should be impossible from the technical standpoint due to the supposed encryption of the card. But alas my tablet is special, because even when used as internal storage, the SD card can be accessed as is. I even in desperation inadvertently would have destroyed the encryption key had it been actually generated because once I learnt I need a rooted phone in order to extract it I unlocked the bootloader w/o realizing all the implications.

Since my question was about the initial reason it came up damaged, I guess I need to include the FS scan log:

```
The type of the file system is FAT32.
Volume Serial Number is 0403-0201
The \ entry contains а nonvalid link.
Windows is verifying files and folders...
File and folder verification is complete.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.
15 437 824 КВ total disk sрасе.
32 КВ in 1 hidden files.
10 336 КВ in 323 folders.
4826 720 КВ in 1 118 files.
10 704 КВ available.

32 768 bytes in each allocation unit.
482 432 total allocation units оп disk.
331 272 allocation units available оп disk.
```